# Identify an Object by property or type

Tags: oop, design-patterns, abstract-class

I have a question regarding the design pattern in java.

I have a class named **Bottle**.
Now, I have two kinds of **Bottle**: glass bottle, and metal bottle.

Which of the following design patterns should I use:
1. Set type of bottle as its property

```
    class Bottle {
        public enum BottleType { GLASS, METAL }

        BottleType type;
    }
```

2. Use inheritance

```
    abstract class Bottle {
    }

    class GlassBottle extends Bottle {
    }

    class MetalBotle extends Bottle {
    }
```

**Update my question**
Bottle will be processed by a processor named BottleProcessor

```
    class BottleProcessor {
        public static breakBottle(Bottle _bottle) {
            //TODO: break bottle
            if _bottle is glass bottle 
                breakGlassBottle()
            else if _bottle is metal bottle 
                breakMetalBottle()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Impossible to answer. It depends on what you further plan to do with these objects. With no implementation whatsoever, the enum is the obvious choice.

Comment: Using inheritance is the Java way.  You can get the specific class name from the instance with getClass().getSimpleName(), or something like that.

Comment: @AdrianM. I very strongly disagree. Effective Java #16: "Favour composition over inheritance"

Comment: Compose one bottle type in another?  What?

Comment: Compose the type of the bottle into the bottle. With no implementation, inheritance gives zero benefits here, and introduces two additional classes.

Comment: That doesn't sound like actual composition.  This is a C-style approach.

Comment: Why not a break instance method?

Comment: @plalx I do not implement Bottle.break() method to avoid dependency on another object. For example, Bottle.break() may calls BottleProcessor.doSomething() then you have to import BottleProcessor into Bottle.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's difficult to answer given no further plan to do, the second option is usually better. But let's call it Polymorphism instead of Inheritance because you can achieve the benefit of this option by not only the `extends` keyword but also the `implements` keyword.

Code like this:

```
interface Bottle {
    void doBreak();
}

class GlassBottle implements Bottle {
    public void doBreak() { ... }
}

class MetalBottle implements Bottle {
    public void doBreak() { ... }
}

class BottleProcessor {
    public static breakBottle(Bottle _bottle) {
        // here I don't know don't care about detailed things like Glass or Metal
        // I just call:
        _bottle.doBreak();
    }
}
```

The benefit of this design is that there won't be a big/god class like in the first option. The `Bottle` class in the first option is an indicator of a violation of the Single Responsibility Principle since it handles many kinds of bottles. So, if your app changes a little bit due to a particular kind of bottle, the whole code will be affected. This can be frustrated in many cases.